# Find non crossing pairs in array and remove iteratively in Python until no pairs are left

Tags: python, arrays, performance

I have a list of tuples containing start and end index points as pairs in an array.

```
(2,72), (20,73),(22,70), (25,30)
```

I want to extract a pair, say A, such that no other pair in the array has a start or end index in A's range. For example here, first time I extract `(25,30)` since no other pair has a starting or end point in the range 25 to 30. Once I extract that, I am left with:

```
(2,72), (20,73),(22,70)
```

Then I extract `(22,70)`, this leaves the list with:

```
(2,72), (20,73)
```

No pair can be extracted further as `(2,72)` contains 20 within it and `(20,73)` contains 72 within it.

A brute force approach:

1. Assume `list_tuple` is a list of tuples
2. Sort `list_tuple` based on starting index
3. Extract an element from list
4. Check all other pairs if this extracted element satisfies the condition

   1. if not move to next element of sorted list
   2. if condition is true, extract the element, change the list and repeat with this new list

```
Checklist=[(2,72), (20,73),(22,70), (25,30)]
sortedlist=sorted(Checklist,key=itemgetter(0))
i=0
NewList=list()
len_sortedlist=len(sortedlist)
while i< len_sortedlist:
    condition=True
    checkpair =sortedlist[i]
    removelist=copy.deepcopy(sortedlist)
    del removelist[i]
    for pair in removelist:# check for every pair if it is within checked pair list
        if pair[0] in range(checkpair[0],checkpair[1]) or pair[1] in range(checkpair[0],checkpair[1]) :
            condition=False
            i=i+1
            break    
    if condition==True:
        NewList.append(checkpair)
        sortedlist.remove(checkpair)
        sortedlist=sorted(sortedlist,key=itemgetter(1))
        i=0
        len_sortedlist=len(sortedlist)
```

I want to know if there's is a better and more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using a `itertools` function like [ifilter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter) ?

```
>>> import itertools
>>> 
>>> def check_element(checkpair):
...     for pair in checklist:
...         if  checkpair != pair and (pair[0] in range(checkpair[0],checkpair[1]) or pair[1] in range(checkpair[0],checkpair[1]) ):
...             return bool
... 
>>> checklist = [(2,72), (20,73),(22,70), (25,30)]
>>> print checklist
[(2, 72), (20, 73), (22, 70), (25, 30)]
>>> filtered = itertools.ifilter(check_element, checklist) #returns generator
>>> checklist = list(filtered)                             #exahust iterator to create list
>>> print checklist
[(2, 72), (20, 73), (22, 70)]
>>> _filtered = itertools.ifilter(check_element, checklist)
>>> checklist = list(_filtered)
>>> print checklist
[(2, 72), (20, 73)]
```